# Running dynamic shell script from php

Tags: php, shell, command, text-to-speech

i've been writing a simple text to speech php script that works with festvox, i've been trying to use it but it seems the part i cant get is running the text to wave converter, shell script. here is the code i've created so far,

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
Say: <input type="text" name="say" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php
$myFile = "test.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $_GET["say"];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
shell_exec('text2wave /var/www/text.txt -otype aiff -o /var/www/out.aiff');
?>
```

so i was wondering what possible errors i could have mad, any help?

Comment: One (unrelated) mistake was not leveraging `file_put_contents()`.

Comment: Did you check the error log? Or redirect stderr?

Comment: You probably need to provide the full path to text2wave? /usr/bin/text2wave etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What error messages are you getting? But if I'd to guess from that code, and that shell_exec command works from the CLI, then try using the full path to the text2wave program.

Comment: where can i find my console error log on ubuntu if im running it from php script?

Comment: If you're using Apache as a web server, stderr is most likely outputted to your Apache error log which is located somewhere like /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log.

Comment: i think im getting permission errors so i can do the password in a file thing

Comment: i put this, sudo -u trevorr -S /usr/bin/text2wave /var/www/text.txt -otype aiff -o /var/www/out.aiff < /var/www/pass, and i keep   getting thiis error in the log,

Comment: [sudo] password for www-data: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for www-data: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for www-data: 
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts

Comment: you welcome, but that was only one part, i also needed to give root access to the file with out entering a password just because it was eaier